# What type of file is /dev/core or /proc/kcore?

Tags: linux, scripting, kernel, linux-kernel

While scanning a filesystem for changes with a shellscript, I forgot to exclude `/dev`, so `core` got tested too. Strangely enough, which ever way I test it, it is not consistent for a type:

```
$ if [ -f ./core ] ; then echo file ; else echo something else ; fi
file
$ ls -al core
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Sep 29 15:40 core -> /proc/kcore
$ file core
core: symbolic link to `/proc/kcore' 
$ if test -f core ; then echo file ; else echo something else ; fi
file
$ if /usr/bin/test -f core ; then echo file ; else echo something else ; fi
file
$ if test -h core ; then echo link ; else echo something else ; fi
link
$ if /usr/bin/test -h core ; then echo link ; else echo something else ; fi
link
```

What is going on here?

Comment: A link is a file. [Everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

Comment: @JohnWHSmith that's a good slogan, but more precisely: files and links to files report true for `test -f`, broken links and links to dirs and files report true for `test -h`, and dirs and links to dirs report true for `test -d`.

Comment: @dubiousjim Thx. So what would be the most accurate way to test a directory entry type?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The results of `test` are accurate; you might just need to combine several invocations. If you want only directories and not links to directories, use `test -d path && !test -h path`.

Comment: @dubiousjim Thx again. As I wrote in my original question, I'm scanning a filesystem for changes, any change to be precise. But aparently a cheap (1 call) test returning the type for a random directory entry is a bit more complicated.

Comment: In most shells, `test` and `[` are builtins, so they should be extremely cheap to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `/dev/core` is a symbolic link to the regular file `/proc/kcore`. So both `test -h /dev/core` and `test -f /dev/core` are true: `-h` because it's a symbolic link, `-f` because the target of the symbolic link is a regular file.

Now for what `/proc/kcore` is. It's a regular file, but it's a bit different from the regular files that you're used to. Whenever a program does something with a file (open, read, write, etc.), this is done through a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), i.e. by executing some code in the kernel. The code that gets invoked depends on the filesystem type. For an on-disk filesystem such as ext4 or FAT, this code works out how the pieces of data that make up the file are arranged, and makes calls to the underlying storage layer (e.g. the disk driver) to read and write those pieces. For a network filesystem such as NFS or Samba, this code sends network packets to the file server. For `/proc`, which is the mount point for the [procfs filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), this code displays or modifies kernel data structures.

Most of the files under `/proc` report information about the system, e.g. `/proc/mounts` reports the list of mount points, `/proc/modules` reports the list of loaded modules, `/proc/123/stat` reports status information about the process with PID 123, etc. The file `/proc/kcore` reports the content of the physical memory of the system, in a format suitable for a debugger, so reading bytes from `/proc/kcore` essentially reads the content of the physical memory.

Files on the procfs filesystem can be considered “magic”, somewhat in the same way that [device files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) are “magic”. Device files and filesystems like procfs and [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) get their magic in different ways: device files can be created on any (well, most) filesystems, they're magic because their directory entry says “block device” of “character device” instead of “regular file”; files under `/proc` and `/sys` are magic because the whole filesystem that they're on is magic.

Except that, as we saw above, there's no actual magic involved. It's just kernel code, whether that code calculates block layouts and reads them from a disk or formats kernel data structures.

You can see the documentation for the procfs filesystem in the [`proc` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

Answer (score 0):

The `/dev/core` file is a link to `/proc/kcore`. The kcore file is a virtual file only existing as part of the [proc filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt). It contains the memory the kernel can allocate. On 64-bit systems the size of `/proc/kcore` is even 128TB, because that's the absolute limit of what 64-bit systems can allocate. This file is formatted like an [ELF binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). See (and notice the file size):

```
$ file /proc/kcore 
/proc/kcore: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, [...]
$ ls -lh /proc/kcore 
-r-------- 1 root root 128T Sep 29 20:01 /proc/kcore
```

---

The `ctime` and `mtime` are equal to the time I called the `ls` command,  because the file only exists then as a file, not before and not after; only in that moment.

So it seems like a regular file, but, as all other files in the proc filesystem, it is only **virtual**. The kernel abstacts the allocatable memory as a file, when you request it. That means that it is only *available* when a [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) or a [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call requests it (`stat()` happens when you use the `test` utility against the file). The kernel then intercepts or catches the system call and gives specific values, instead of the *real* content, which does not exist. If you read `/proc/kcore` as a file (with `cat` for example), the kernel does memory reads.

Behind every file in the proc filesystem is a handler function, which is responsible what should be given back as file contents.

Since the `/proc/kcore` is in ELF format, the contents are designed to be examined by a debugger, such as `gdb`.

Comment: Let me add a comment  and mention that /proc/kcore is a file that is in conflict with the /proc filesystem definition, it only exists in Linux. The /proc filesystem paper from AT&T explains that /proc contains special files related to processes and only for processes.  The device with the same behavior on a genetic UNIX is called `/dev/mem`.